# Products of square roots in a list using `Reduce`

Tags: java, python, reduce

Let's say I want to compute product of the square roots of each element in List. 
The same can be achieved in Java like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Double> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
        arrays.add(4.0);
        arrays.add(9.0);
        arrays.add(16.0);

        double i = arrays.stream().reduce(1.0, (a, b) -> (a * Math.sqrt(b)),
                                                         (a, b) -> (a * b));
        System.out.println(i);

    };
}
```

Output:

```
24.0
```

How can I achieve the same in Python. Below gives incorrect.

```
  >>> reduce(lambda a,b: math.sqrt(a)*math.sqrt(b), [4,9,16])
  9.797958971132712
```

Since it's equivalent to

```
>>> math.sqrt(math.sqrt(4)*math.sqrt(9))*math.sqrt(16)
```

However the same syntax in Java gives different result. How it computes that?

```
double i = arrays.stream().reduce(1.0, (a, b) -> (Math.sqrt(a) * Math.sqrt(b)));
```

Output:

```
8.23906857562847
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the initial value to implement the same logic as in java, here the first parameter *x* acts as the accumulated value which is initialized by 1:

```
from functools import reduce
from math import sqrt 

reduce(lambda x, y: x * sqrt(y), [4,9,16], 1)
# 24.0
```

If you don't provide the initial value, it will start from the first element in the sequence.

With the initial value, this should be equivalent to your last java example:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: sqrt(x) * sqrt(y), [4,9,16], 1)
# 8.23906857562847
```